# Css nth-child works strange

Tags: html, css

I try to make a striped table. But when I try to use nth-child, it works really strange

template:

```
...
<tr class="striped">...</tr>
<tr class="more">...</tr>
...
```

css:

```
tr.striped:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color : rgba($mainColor, .1);
}
```

But all tr with striped class were colored. Maybe I miss some feature of specification?

Comment: Is this (https://jsfiddle.net/o1dtcs5d/1/) how you want it?

Comment: Here's another working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOEKvR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1)
```

instead of:

```
tr.striped:nth-child(odd)
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/epnjn1wo/

Comment: Because tr.striped are always in odd position.

Comment: I'm not English, but I will try to add more detail about this, your welcome.

Comment: So am I. I just could not understand why there is no different between tr:nth-child(odd) and tr.striped:nth-child(odd). It's very odd for me)